# Given the high resolution signal and the low pass filter (kaiser filter), is there a way to reconstruct the low resolution signal?

Tags: reference-request, filters, signal-processing, upsampling, downsampling

When we upsampling a discrete 1d signal by 2x, we first interleave the signal by 0, then pass through a low pass filter.

low resolution signal [x1, x2, x3, x4] -> interleave 0 -> [x1, 0, x2, 0, x3, 0, x4] -> low pass filter (kaiser filter, convolution) -> high resolution signal

Given the high resolution signal and the low pass filter (kaiser filter), is there a way to reconstruct the low resolution signal? If there is not a way to perform precise reconstruction, is there a way to perform roughly reconstruction?

Comment: I Think you'll have more luck if you move the question to the [signal processing communiy](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/#:~:text=Signal%20Processing%20Stack%20Exchange%20is,a%20minute%20to%20sign%20up.)

Comment: Thank for a lot. I will try it.